# use application lib instead of app server lib

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, application-server, wildfly

I will create an enterprise project in eclipse and use Wildfly application server.
In my project i have some library that may be exists in Wildfy `lib` folder.
How can i say to application server, if you need any library that exist in your `lib` and my project `lib`, please use that library that is exist in my project.
For example Wildfly contains JSF implementation and i will use Primefaces. I add Primefaces libraries to my project class path, and i will Wildfly use it, but Wildfly use its own instance.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it isn't that easy.  JBoss has introduced the concept of modules.  You'll need to understand how they work if you want to override library versions that JBoss provides.  Check out the documentation here:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

and

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Implicit+module+dependencies+for+deployments

Comment: Thank you for the link updates... not sure how I missed that :-/

Answer (score 1):

If you add a library to your `lib` directory WildFly will include those libraries in you class path. Which means if you include Primefaces you will get Primefaces in your class path. WildFly does not include Primefaces as a module.

For server dependencies, like the JSF implementation, WildFly will load it's provided dependency first before the one in your `lib` directory. That said you don't really want to be overriding implementations like this. It's part of the Java EE specification and will be provided by any Java EE compliant server.

You should also read the links that [jgitter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308571/jgitter) suggested.